# Oracle Insert query

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I am getting this error "ORA-01722: illegal/invalid number"

```
            decimal first2var = Convert.ToDecimal(var1);
            decimal id_refeicao;

            //...
            // save values in var insted of lables
            decimal id_usuario = (decimal)dr.GetInt32(0);
            //...
            var idUsuarioParameter = new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "id_usuario",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = id_usuario
            };
            var idRefeicaoParameter = new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "id_refeicao",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = id_refeicao
            };
            var var1Parameter = new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "first2var",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal, //-- populate with correct oracle type
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = first2var
            };
                OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(oradb);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SER_REFEICAO_USUARIO (USUARIO, REFEICAO, DATA_HORA, ORIGEM ) VALUES(:id_usuario, :id_refeicao, SYSDATE , :first2var )";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(idUsuarioParameter);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(idRefeicaoParameter);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(var1Parameter);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
```

Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong here, if i hard code my values in my insert query, it works fine but if i pass the parameters as above so i got the error.

Comment: Why do you have `var2` in your command tex, but add `var1` as a parameter? Also, are the ids numeric or strings?

Comment: @DanielKelley ids are numeric but i defined there data type string, like this "string id_usuario"

Comment: What about the definition of table `SER_REFEICAO_USUARIO`, can you tell us what type each of the columns is?

Comment: Well thanks. i found the problem and the problem is, I am not defining the OracleCommand() so it was taking the old values and using the old values in the query.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [source](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/parameters.html), you should omit the `:` from your parameter names, so it should be like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("id_usuario", id_usuario);
cmd.Parameters.Add("id_refeicao", id_refeicao);
cmd.Parameters.Add("var1", var1);
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you have a mismatch between your query text:

```
INSERT INTO SER_REFEICAO_USUARIO (USUARIO, REFEICAO,    DATA_HORA,  ORIGEM)
 VALUES(:id_usuario, :id_refeicao, SYSDATE, :var2 )
```

And your parameter declarations:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("var1", var1);
```

Comment: @alykins, here's a starting point: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @SvenGrosen here is my query with hard coded values
"INSERT INTO SER_REFEICAO_USUARIO (USUARIO, REFEICAO,ORIGEM, DATA_HORA) VALUES(139773, 68, SYSDATE , 02 )

Comment: @user2956373 Then what happens if you don't do a `ToString()` and define `id_usuario` and `id_refeicao` as ints?

Comment: @SvenGrosen i just tried with out ToString() but same error illegal variable number/name

Comment: @SvenGrosen i have updated my question with my whole code, can you give me something what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using ODP.NET. In my experience, I always have to specify the OracleDbType.Decimal because for some reason Oracle doesn't like byte, int, or long.  Another issue is we're not passing the OracleDbType along with the parameter, so ODP.NET is seeing that you passed in a string and is probably saying the parameter is of type string and not of the type you want.  This coupled with Sven Grosen's answer should do it for you. you end up with something like below:

```
decimal id_usuario = (decimal)dr.GetInt32(0);
decimal id_refeicao = (decimal)dtre.GetInt32(0);
var idUsuarioParameter = new OracleParameter
{
    ParameterName = "id_usuario",
    OracelDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
    Value = id_usuario
};
var idRefeicaoParameter = new OracleParameter
{
    ParameterName = "id_refeicao",
    OracelDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
    Value = id_refeicao 
};    
var var1Parameter = new OracleParameter
{
    ParameterName = "var1",
    //OracelDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal, -- populate with correct oracle type
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
    Value = var1 
};


connection.Open();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SER_REFEICAO_USUARIO (USUARIO, REFEICAO,    DATA_HORA,  ORIGEM) VALUES(:id_usuario, :id_refeicao, SYSDATE, :var1 )";
cmd.Parameters.Add(idUsuarioParameter);
cmd.Parameters.Add(idRefeicaoParameter);
cmd.Parameters.Add(var1Parameter);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

I think that should do it for you.  NOTE: untested/uncompiled code.

Comment: i tried the way you mentioned above but still i am getting error "ORA-01036 illegal variable name/number" ..

Comment: another thing i am not able to put OracleDbType.Decimal, it is not accepting this at this line

Comment: I've updated the code to explicitly create the OracleParameter types before adding them to the cmd.Parameters collection.  The important part here is we are telling Oracle what type we're using.

Comment: can you give me you id. i would like to discuss whole code and its logic with you.. Thanks

Comment: SO doesn't provide a means for user to user messaging, we can discuss here or you can open a new question and link it here, and I can respond. This way others who find this post will have the answers to your questions as well.

Comment: i have updated my question with my complete code. i tried your way by hard-coded the values it works fine but the way i was trying to do above have same error and i am sure it is at the time of insertion but what exactly it is i am not able to find it out

Comment: Instead of using cmd.Parameters.Add(...) try creating a new OracleParameter object like I did, minimally populating the ParameterName, OracleDbType, Direction, and Value properties, and then add that object using cmd.Parameters.Add(myOracleParameter)

Comment: yes i did same as you did you can see in my code which i just posted above.

Comment: i think you are trying to say that i do same in my first select statement, right ?

Comment: I'm saying that every time you add a parameter to your OracleCommand object you (usually) need to specify the type. So when you do cmd.Parameters.Add(myParmName, myParmValue) you're not telling ODP.NET what the type of the parameter is, so it looks at the runtime type of myParmValue to infer the OracleDbType. Avoid this runtime type inference by specifying it. You can specify the parameter type by explicitly creating a parameter (like I did). Do this for every parameter in your method.

Comment: Well thanks. i found the problem and the problem is, I am not defining the OracleCommand() so it was taking the old values and using the old values in the query.